# Mongodb: loaded javascript function not excecuting properly

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have a db called db1, and a collection called places.
If I do:

```
use db1;

use places;

db.places.find().pretty();
```

I get the proper results from the collection, but if I load the following javascript file, I do not get any results:

```
 var query1 = function(){
    db.places.find().pretty();
 };
```

I'm loading the proper js file, from the correct directory with this command:
    load('test.js');
I'm actually running mongo in the same directory where the js file is.
After loading it and calling the function query1(); I don't get any results.
I'm running mongo shell version 2.6.3, Ubuntu 14.04 32 bit; I had a previous version on my old computer which had Ubuntu 12.04 and didn't have this issue when loading js files.
Hope you can help me-
Thanks!

Comment: try with `return db.places.find().pretty();` in query1?

Comment: That was it, thank you, it was obvious but also one of those things you forget once in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is you are not returning the values from your function.

Just do like bellow

```
var query1 = function(){
    return db.places.find().pretty();
};
```